# CSS padding and margin not working?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

For some reason the padding and margin for my CSS aren't working

```css
.optinfield {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row clearfix" data-mode="optin">
      <div class="column full" >
        <div class="margin-20" style="text-align: center;">  
         <form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="optin-form" action="http://localhost:3000/landing_pages/optin" method="post">

            <input id="optin-external-id" name="optin_external_id" type="hidden" value="{optin_external_id}">

            <input id="optin-tags" class="optinfield" name="tags" type="hidden" value="">
            <input id="optin-redirect-url" name="redirect_url" type="hidden" value="http://">
            <input id="optin-from-url" name="from_url" type="hidden">

            <input id="optin-first-name" class="optinfield" name="contact[first_name]" placeholder="First Name" required="required" type="text" >
            <br>
            <input id="optin-last-name" class="optinfield" name="contact[last_name]" placeholder="Last Name" required="required" type="text">
            <br>
            <input id="optin-email" class="optinfield" name="contact[email]" placeholder="Email" required="required" type="email" >
            <br>
            
            <div style="margin:1em 0 2.5em;">
              <input class="btn btn-primary full-width" id="optin-submit" name="commit" title="Add me to the list." type="submit" value="Submit">
              <br>
            </div>
          </form>

          <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("optin-submit").addEventListener("click", function(clickEvent) {
              document.getElementById("optin-from-url").value = window.location.href
            });
          </script>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have read in a few questions that if I set `display: inline-block;`
 that it should work but for me it still does not work.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: currently it looks like [image]

and it should look like [image]

Comment: something must be missing. I used a screen capture from my view of the screen and the buttons have the vertical spacing you want. It may be that you have styles on some other element of the page and that is constraining these elements. Can you give us more of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding !important at the end of the padding and margin and it worked great

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine. What is it you expect?

```js
document.getElementById("optin-submit").addEventListener("click", function(clickEvent) {
  document.getElementById("optin-from-url").value = window.location.href
});
```

```css
.optinfield {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row clearfix" data-mode="optin">
  <div class="column full">
    <div class="margin-20" style="text-align: center;">
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="optin-form" action="http://localhost:3000/landing_pages/optin" method="post">

        <input id="optin-external-id" name="optin_external_id" type="hidden" value="{optin_external_id}">

        <input id="optin-tags" class="optinfield" name="tags" type="hidden" value="">
        <input id="optin-redirect-url" name="redirect_url" type="hidden" value="http://">
        <input id="optin-from-url" name="from_url" type="hidden">

        <input id="optin-first-name" class="optinfield" name="contact[first_name]" placeholder="First Name" required="required" type="text">
        <br>
        <input id="optin-last-name" class="optinfield" name="contact[last_name]" placeholder="Last Name" required="required" type="text">
        <br>
        <input id="optin-email" class="optinfield" name="contact[email]" placeholder="Email" required="required" type="email">
        <br>

        <div style="margin:1em 0 2.5em;">
          <input class="btn btn-primary full-width" id="optin-submit" name="commit" title="Add me to the list." type="submit" value="Submit">
          <br>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i added some pics to show you what i need, also i accidentally edited your post sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues and it really depends on what you are looking for. First, you are using 100% of the width for each box. Cut that down to a smaller amount (say 30%) and you can see the individual boxes. That still lines them up vertically, however, because you have manual line breaks between them. That seems to work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: IN your original post you had padding:12px 20px, but I notice that in the code you are showing now the padding is missing from the optin styles. That would do it. If you add the padding pack in it should work.

Comment: thats what i am saying, for some reason it is not adding the padding when i load the page and i don't know why

Answer (score 1):

The 20px padding for "optinfield" is moving the text within the input field and not outside. 
If you want to move all the block - the form with the image and the text - all this to the right, you should change the width of the container div, which is right now set to "column full", or give it the space you need.
You also have there some class "margin-20" which I don't know what it is, 
you've uploaded the form only, and the form has no problem :)